# VLOOKUP function in Cognito?

Tags: cognito-forms, vlookup

I want to fill automatically name, address, etc. when a customer fills its customer code.

Is there a function like Excel's VLOOKUP in Cognito Forms?

Where should I host my database and how can I make them communicate?

Answer (score 1):

We are planning to add this feature to [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in October/November.  Please up vote and comment on this feature on our Idea Board!

https://trello.com/c/sgDIKA7o